# How to Solve an Integral when $~x~$ is added to $~f(x)~$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was given the problem: $$\int _0^{3} x + f(x) dx $$
It was accompanied by a graph:
[image: graph of function]

I did $3 + 5 = 8$. But, the answer key says $4.5+5=9.5$.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The $5$ is correct of course. To integrate $x$, we add 1 to the power and divide by the new power, 2. This gives us $x^2/2$. We then take the difference of this at the end points, i.e. $(3^2 - 0^2)/2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use linearity: $$\int\limits_0^3 (x+f(x))\, dx=\int\limits_0^3 x\, dx+\int\limits_0^3f(x)\, dx,$$ and compute them separately. It looks to me like you integrated $f$ correctly and $x$ incorrectly. For the $x$ integral, you should instead have that $$\int\limits_0^3 x\, dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\Big|_{x=0}^{x=3}=\frac{9}{2},$$ like your answer key says.

Comment: Why is the x interval $\frac{x^2}2$?

Comment: I just found the anti-derivative and evaluated it. If you haven’t learned this, you can compute the area between the curve and the x-axis pretty easily (it’s a nice triangle).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to integrate the $x$ in the expression.  If you know that the integral of $f(x)$ is $5$, then $\displaystyle\int_0^3 x + f(x) dx$ would result in $(3^2)/2 + 5 = 4.5 + 5$

Comment: This might be a really basic question, but why did you divide $3^2$ by 2?

Comment: The anti-derivative of $x$ is $\dfrac{x^2}{2}$. So when you evaluate at 3 you get $\dfrac{9}{2}$.